# "I don't think so" vs. "I think not"

Tags: colloquialisms, negation

I've recently been told that "I don't think so" is, in the U.S.A., a southernism, whereas "I think not" is considered more acceptable everywhere else.  Is this true?

Example:

> Q: *Is your wrist broken?*
>   A: *I don't think so.* / *I think not.*

Comment: My impression was that "I don't think so" is an Americanism and "I think not" a Briticism. However, [Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+do+not+think+so%2CI+think+not&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) disagrees; there isn't much difference in usage in the British and American Ngrams.

Answer (score 10):

I think not!  In British English, *I don't think so.* and *I think not.* are both used, although they have different nuances.

*I don't think so.* is more common, and shows a little diffidence or uncertainty.

> A: Is it going to rain today?
>
> B: I don't think so.  I'd just wear a t-shirt if I were you.

*I think not.* is used to disagree emphatically.

> A: You still owe me.
>
> B: I think not!  If I hear any more from you about this, you'll be hearing from my solicitor.

Sorry, but I don't have any references I can cite.  Just my personal experience.

Comment: I think not! The only reason that form seems more "emphatic" is because it's dated/format, so it calls more attention to the fact of disagreement. In common relaxed parlance, *"I don't think so"* often occurs in contexts where we're trying to **downplay** the disjunct (i.e. - we don't want to come right out and say "**I disagree**").

Comment: I'm confused.  You wrote "I think not!" but you seem to be agreeing with me!  I wrote *diffidence and uncertainty*: you wrote *downplay the disjunct*.  Where's the difference?  I wrote that *I think not.* is less common and is used to disagree emphatically: you wrote that it is dated and calls more attention to the fact of disagreement.  Again, where's the difference?

Comment: On reflection I probably got carried away there. All I meant was that *in and of themselves* the two forms don't carry different meanings - it's just that the "dated/formal" one is more likely to be *used* only in certain situations. Often for emphasis, sometimes light-heartedly. I'll leave the first comment there because I still stand by that *reasoning*, but I fully accept it doesn't conflict with your answer (which I now somewhat belatedly upvote! :)

Answer (score 4):

*I think not* is a formal way of saying no. It's often used in parody, faux and overly dramatic situations, to heighten the negation and introduce a sense of inadequacy, foolishness and insignificance.

Comment: What about "I don't think so"?

Comment: Have you any evidence for these claims?

Comment: @jwpat7: NGram doesn't handle apostrophes well, but in Google Books *"I don't think so"* outweighs *"I do not think so"* about 3:1. And *"I think not"*, which used to be more common, is now perceived as archaic/stilted/formal. So effectively, Andrew is correct here.