# Examples of verbs that can be negated with not instead of don't

Tags: grammaticality

There are some examples of verbs in English that can be negated with not:

> I think not

However it seems that this statement must exist in isolation and  it is incorrect in modern English to follow this with a statement:

> <s>I think not the shop is closed</s> I don't think the shop is closed

Another common example is:

> We need not call the police

This sounds natural in modern English. However in general this type of negation is not possible:

> <s>I drive not to work</s>

Are there any rules on when this type of negation is possible in modern English? Can you give any more examples of verbs for which this is possible?

Comment: @Shoe "Hope/wish not to" is not the same as "don't hope/wish to".  "I don't wish to go with you" means you have no desire to go; "I wish not to go with you" means you really prefer to stay behind.

Comment: worth searching here for "need not" -- there's some information under that search term on semi-modal auxiliary verbs such as *need*, *dare*, and *ought*.

Comment: "Ask not what your country can do for you, ask what you can do for your country." John F. Kennedy, Inaugural Address, 1961.

Comment: Another user asked a very similar question, but not as well written, and it is now deleted. Only users with 10K can see it https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/416131/what-verbs-can-be-put-into-the-negative-form-by-adding-not-instead-of-dont

Comment: "I drive not to work, but to visit my friends." Not only is this a valid, grammatical sentence, but the way not is functioning is exactly the same way it functions in "I think not" -- it's negating something after/other-than the verb.

Comment: Probably the most important examples are "can not," "do not," etc.

Comment: Why haven't anybody thought of have not?

Comment: @Bent Or do not? They're the verb's auxiliaries.

Comment: There is not a single example I can think of.

Comment: I agree with @R..—both "I think not the shop is closed" and "I drive not to work" are perfectly valid and sensical sentences.  They do *not* mean the same thing as "I think that the shop is not closed" and "I do not drive to work", respectively—but why would you expect them to have the same meaning when they are different sentences?

Comment: @Infiltrator To my English ears the sentence "I think not the shop is closed" sounds extremely strange and would leave me confused. I would respond with "you *don't* think the shop is closed?" seeking clarification of what has been said.

Comment: @JackPierce-Brown, oh, it is certainly a weird sentence, to be sure.  (By the way, it means that something, which is not the shop, is closed.)  It might make a little a more sense if you read it out loud and put exaggerated pauses before and after "not the shop"—"I think PAUSE not the shop PAUSE is closed."

Comment: This reminds me of a joke. It starts 'A piece of string walks into a bar...' and ends with '... and the string replied "I'm a frayed knot" '.

Comment: Could one linguistically parse the 'not' as not an adverb modifying the noun, but as a weird pronoun referring negatively about an antecedent, like a counterpart to the [pronoun-like 'so'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19394/is-so-a-pronoun#comment181735_19662)

Comment: @JackPierce-Brown: observe the difference between "I drive not to work" and "I don't drive to work". In the former, I generally drive, but not to work. In the latter, I do not drive to work (and it's unmentioned whether I drive in general). The same is true for other examples you listed. "We don't need to call the police" = there is no requirement for us to call the police, but we can do so if we want. "We need not call the police" = we **must** [not call the police] (i.e. it's not allowed to do so even if we want to)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There are other verbs that follow this pattern, including:

- *believe* (Is he here yet? I believe not.)
- *expect* (Will he get here before eight? I expect not.)
- *hope* (Will he be out until midnight? I hope not.)
- *guess* (Will we have time for dinner? I guess not.)
- *be afraid* (Have you heard anything from him? I'm afraid not.)
- *appear* (Did he leave on time? It appears not.)
- *assume* (Did he get our message? I assume not.)
- *imagine* (Will he think to call us? I imagine not.)
- *presume* (Does he have a good excuse? I presume not.)
- *seem* (Does he care at all? It seems not.)
- *suppose* (Does it matter? I suppose not.)

(Here is an [article](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/so-and-such/so-and-not-with-expect-hope-think-etc) that explains their use.)

However, I disagree that in "I think not" the "not" is negating "think" – rather, it's negating the (implicit) proposition that the speaker doesn't believe is true.

For one thing, the equivalent with "don't" is "I don't think *so*", where the *so* is clearly referring back to the proposition being discussed. This can be used in the positive, too, as "I think so"; the "not" replaces the "so" in the negative case. So, I'd say that the sentence

> (Will he arrive on time?) *I think not.*

is not equivalent to

> *I don't think he will arrive on time.*

but rather

> *I think he will not arrive on time.*

In this case the meaning is almost identical, but for some of the other verbs it is not, and for example:

> (Will he arrive on time?) *I'm afraid not.*

is definitely equivalent to

> I'm afraid he will not arrive on time.

and certainly not

> I'm not afraid he will arrive on time.

Similarly, "I hope not" would mean "I hope he will not arrive on time" rather than "I don't hope he will arrive on time".

Comment: Hence the clear (but often misunderstood) difference between *not liking* someone and *disliking* someone.

Comment: It is very interesting to note that these are all verbs that trigger the subjunctive (true in English, but perhaps more easily seen with their Spanish equivalents). Further, this highlights the difference that you point out with “I think not”: “I don’t think that he will arrive on time” is subjunctive “No creo que llegue a tiempo,” while “I think that he will not arrive on time” is indicative “Creo que no llegará a tiempo”.

Comment: @wchargin there's not a smack of the subjunctive in *I don't think that he will arrive on time*. If it's "easier to see" with its "Spanish equivalent"  it's because that language has a subjunctive case whilst English  long ago abandoned it; its discarded remains survive in a handful of uses, *not* including the sentences  you talk about.

Comment: Interestingly  the Cambridge blog which explains the usage of these verbs contains not the word *subjunctive*.

Comment: Spanish has a subjunctive _mood_; nouns have to stay in cases, but verbs can get into moods. The word is related to _mode_ and _modal_, like _can, should, will, may, might, dare, need, must,_ etc, all of which can be negated with _not_ because they're auxiliary verbs (like _be, have,_ and _do_).

Answer (score 10):

There is no hard and fast rule, but the *OED* points out in its third definition of *not* that this construction was much more common prior to modern English, and certain words have maintained this construction since early modern English, while others have switched to the standard convention of using **do not**.

> **3.** Following a full verb. Now chiefly arch. or literary and humorous.
>
> *In recent use, esp. in I kid you not and variants.*
>
> F. T. Visser ( Hist. Syntax Eng. Lang. (1969) III. §1441) observes that from the beginning of the modern English period certain verbs tended to continue to be used in this construction rather than the do not construction, **the main ones being *care, doubt, know, mistake, trow*, and *wot***.

This list provided in the *OED* note is not comprehensive as far as the construction is used in modern English. Afterall, it doesn't include *think*, as pointed out in the question, or *kid*, as pointed out in their example of the recent phrase "I kid you not."  But the note does show that this construction appears to have *remained in use* for certain words, while other constructions switched to use the **do not** construction in modern English.

That brings us to another relevant point, which is that this construction of *not* was more common in archaic use.  A few examples from the *OED* citations show how it was applied earlier:

> As longe as the significacion bode, **it hurted not.**

- William Tyndale · *An answere vnto Sir Thomas Mores dialoge* · 1st edition, **1531** (1 vol.).

> With holy father **sits not** with such thinges to mell.

- Edmund Spenser · *The faerie queene* · 1st edition, **1590** (1 vol.).

Answer (score 6):

**Short answer**

In sentences such as *I think not*, the word *not* is a proform standing in for a negated subordinate clause. It is not negating the verb *think*. Rather it is the complement of that verb. We use *not* in the same places where we use *so* to represent positive subordinate clauses.

- Has Bob eaten yet?
- I think [Bob hasn't eaten yet].
- I think [not].
- I think [Bob has eaten].
- I think [so].

Because *not* represents a subordinate clause here, it does not make the larger sentence negative.

---

**Full answer**

**1. Verbal negation in finite clauses:**

The word *not* is often used to negate clauses. When occurring in finite clauses, it occurs after the auxiliary verb (apart from in some types of question, where the auxiliary moves to the front of the clause leaving the word *not* in situ).

If there is no auxiliary verb, we need to insert the dummy auxiliary, *do*:

1. The elephants are swimming.
2. The elephants **are not** swimming.
3. My elephants swim.
4. My elephants **do not**  swim.
5. *My elephants **not** swim. (ungrammatical).

We can show that the word *not* belongs with the auxiliary here by 'contracting' *not* with the auxiliary verb:

6. The elephants **aren't** swimming.

The reason that we can use *not* in the Original Poster's sentence *We need not tell the police* is that the verb *need* is an auxiliary verb here. We can show this by using a contraction:

- We **needn't** tell the police.

Notice that this whole sentence is therefore negative. We can show this by using a question tag. Negative sentences always take positive tags:

- We needn't tell the police, need we?
- *We needn't tell the police, needn't we? (ungrammatical)

---

**2. Proforms**

We often use proforms in English to refer back to a previously mentioned phrase or clause (what's really happening of course, is that we're referring back to a previously mentioned entity or idea). For example, we often use pro**nouns** to refer back to a previously mentioned noun phrase, where the pronoun replaces the whole noun phrase , not just the noun:

- See **that man in the red t-shirt**? **He** is my Maths teacher.

In the example above the pronoun *he* is standing in for the previously mentioned phrase *that man in the red t-shirt*. We also have proforms, such as the word *there*, for example, which stand in for whole preposition phrases:

- We were **at the bottom of the valley**. It was very beautiful **there**.

In the example above the proform *there* is standing in for the *at*-preposition phrase *at the bottom of the valley*.

If we want to use a proform for a whole clause, we often use the proform *so*.

7. Has Bob finished his work?
8. Well, he said **so**.
9. Well, he said **he has finished his work**.

In the examples above we can see that the word *so* is replacing a clause as the complement of the verb *said*. The clause that has been replaced means something like *he has finished his work*.

Notice however, that *so* can't replace a negative clause. If we want to replace a negative clause with a proform, we have to use the proform *not*, which stands in for negative clauses:

11. He didn't eat it, did he?
12. I think **so**. (= "I think **he ate it**")
13. I think **not**. (= "I think **he didn't eat it**)

Notice that although *not* represents a negative subordinate clause here, it doesn't make the larger sentence negative. We can show this by putting a negative tag at the end of the sentence:

14. You think not, don't you?

---

**Conclusion**

In the Original Poster's sentence, *I think not*, the word *not* is a pro-clause item standing in for a negative clause. It represents a subordinate clause functioning as the complement of the verb *think*. It does not negate the verb *think* or make the larger sentence negative. We can use *not* or 
*so* as a proform with many other verbs that take subordinate clauses.

Below is an excerpt on pro-form *so* and *not* from *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Huddleston & Pullum, 2002 p.849).

---

**Excerpt from the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language:**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Relevant: ["I don't think so" vs. "I think not"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56972/i-dont-think-so-vs-i-think-not)

I would say that the usual form of negation is to include the do as an auxiliary verb.

"I think not" is a colloquialism, but one that implies British upper classes and has grown from there into acceptable usage but usually in an amusing way. Unless you actually are posh, in which case you may use it unironically.

"Need" is different, but I see it as part of the group of verbs like should, would, could, do, and have. This must form a closed group of verbs of some description. The other verbs are often auxiliary verbs while need is not, so maybe that is not it afterall.

Edit: a comment from @Shoe to the original post pointed out that these are modal and semi-modal forms.

Comment: How in the world is "I think not" a COLLOQUIALISM?

Answer (score 0):

Auxiliary verbs are negated directly, while non-auxiliary cannot be negated directly. *Do* is a dummy auxiliary verb; it is put into sentences simply to have an auxiliary verb to negate. For instance, it's not grammatical to say "I eat not broccoli", so the word "do" is put in that sentence just so there will a verb that can be negated: "I do not eat broccoli". Other common auxiliary verbs are *be*, *have*, *can*, *must*, and *will*. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_verb for more. Note that with some auxiliary verbs, there is some ambiguity as to what is being negated. For instance, does "I can not go" mean "Not going is something that I can do", or "Going is not something that I can do"? The word "cannot" helps make it clear that the latter is meant. Contractions can also serve this purpose: "I daren't go" makes it clear that you don't dare to go, not that you dare to not go.

There are also other verbs for which direction negation is permissible with varying degrees of archaicness, such as *ask*, *speak*, *go*, *send* etc.